# frontend maven plugin fails to execute goal

Tags: angular, maven, maven-frontend-plugin

If I run `mvn clean install` for my Angular project, I'm getting the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:npm (npm build) on project client: Failed to run task: 'npm run build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]`

It was working before and I'm also using the same configuration in other projects.

**already tried**

- using different versions for node and npm
- checked configuration of my maven home directory
- invalidated cache and restarted intellij and deleted nodemodules

Any help would be greatly appreciated. See below for relevant parts from pom's and full error log.

**in parent pom**

```
    <modules>
        <module>server</module>
        <module>client</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <frontend.maven.plugin.version>1.4</frontend.maven.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <node.version>v10.15.3</node.version>
        <npm.version>6.4.1</npm.version>
    </properties>
```

**in client pom**

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
          <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${frontend.maven.plugin.version}</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
            <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        <configuration>
          <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
              <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
              <npmDownloadRoot>MYDOWNLOADROOT</npmDownloadRoot>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>npm rebuild</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>rebuild node-sass</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>


          <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>npm build</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

**full error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:npm (npm build) on project client: Failed to run task: 'npm run build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:npm (npm build) on project client: Failed to run task
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute (AbstractFrontendMojo.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'npm run build' failed.
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute (NodeTaskExecutor.java:63)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.NpmMojo.execute (NpmMojo.java:62)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute (AbstractFrontendMojo.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutionException: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute (ProcessExecutor.java:82)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput (ProcessExecutor.java:64)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput (NodeExecutor.java:29)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute (NodeTaskExecutor.java:58)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.NpmMojo.execute (NpmMojo.java:62)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute (AbstractFrontendMojo.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute (ProcessExecutor.java:74)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput (ProcessExecutor.java:64)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput (NodeExecutor.java:29)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute (NodeTaskExecutor.java:58)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.NpmMojo.execute (NpmMojo.java:62)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute (AbstractFrontendMojo.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :client

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: unfortunately the error details are not in the (looong) stack trace, but in the execution of `npm run build` (at `generate-resources` phase), to better analyze, plz: 1. `mvn clean` 2. `npm run build` (3. (shorten above stacktrace, and) update with new)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try running the npm install and npm run build command directly from your project root folder and see what error you are getting. I do not see anything wrong with maven configuration.

If possible share the error or npm-debug.log file created by running npm run build.

Comment: This seems to happen when either NPM or NPM subprocess spawns a new thread.

EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

Comment: When building from the terminal, I have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

When running the react-scripts build on the CI, the build script treats warnings as errors because by default process.env.CI = true.

In your package.json, update build as below to override process.env.CI value to false

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false && react-scripts build",  // Add CI=False here
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```